# How can I make a div cover the entirety of a div behind it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a square-shaped div (the red box) on the page by default. When the user hover the mouse over it, a second div should display with a semi-transparent black background and some text/content. I'm trying to imitate [Devon Stank's project section](https://www.devonstank.com/portfolio/) on his website.

The code I have right now increases the height of the default square red box and the second div doesn't cover the whole of the red box. What's wrong with the code?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3k4zvjr/)

```css
.project-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.default-box {
  background-color: red;
}

.hover-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.default-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.default-box:hover .default-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="default-box project-box">
  <div class="default-hover hover-content">hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: 100%;` won't work on the element if the parent's `height` isn't defined.
Also, if you stick with `position: relative` with a `padding` on the parent, you won't be able to cover it all.

If you want to cover all the `.project-box` (parent) no matter its `padding` values,
I suggest you to use an `absolute` positioning on its child:
(I've done it by adding the new class `.veil`, but it could be done within your existing class)

```css
.project-box {
  position: relative; /* ADDED so that the absolute positioning refers to this parent */
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.default-box {
  background-color: red;
}

.hover-content {
  /* REMOVED position and sizes */
  padding-top: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.default-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.default-box:hover .default-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* ADDED this class */
.veil {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="default-box project-box">
  <!-- Added a class for the child here -->
  <div class="default-hover hover-content veil">hello</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here, it may help you, try it.

```
.project-box {
position: relative;
width: 30%;
height:100%
}

.default-box {
 background-color: red;
 }

.hover-content {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top: 30%;
 }
```